# How to overload operator+ if the calling object is not a class object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
Class fraction
{
public:
      fraction operator+ (const fraction& fr) const;
private:
      int num; //numerator 
      int den; //denominator
};
```

I wanted to overlaod the operator+ so that it perfoms the multiplication of an integer constant (calling object) and a fraction.

```
fraction fraction::operator+ (const fraction& fr) const
{
    fraction result;

    result.num = fr.num + fr.den * (*this);
    //error message says invalid operands to binary exprssion ('int' and 'constant fraction')
    result.den = fr.den;

    simplified_fr(result); // a helper function to simplify the resulted fraction 
    return result;
}
```

It seems that the problem is about the type of calling object. I intended to make it a constant integer but the computer thought it was a 'const fraction'. Can someone please advise me why this happened and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This `new_fr.num = fr.num * (*this);` is pointless, you want to do some `int` arithmetics in the implementation instead of `fraction`; `result.den = fr.den;` this is mathematically wrong.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading?rq=1

Comment: Read this: [MCVE]

Comment: `this->num` instead of `(*this)`? Might I also suggest to dive into `std::ratio`?

Comment: hmm, num is a member of the class object. But the calling object 'this' pointed to is intended to be an integer. So, I didn't quite get how 'this->num' would work?

Comment: Don't insist on using a member-function, and your problems disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to do achieve something like this:

```
fraction fract;
fraction fract2 = 2 + fract;
```

The answer is that you cannot overload **member method** operator+ for non-class objects. BUT you can define/overload global operator+ function:

```
fraction operator+(int num, const fraction& rFrac)
{
//your implementation
}
```

You will probably need access to private members of `fraction` class. That can be acomplished by making operator+ a friend:

```
class fraction
{
    //...
    friend fraction operator+(int num, const fraction& rFrac);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Btw, could a friend function directly use the helper methods of the class?

Comment: @PhyllisQu  Depends, friend means that the function can see private stuff of the class, nothing more. So operator+ can use private static methods and static variables. It can also call private member methods on an instance of the class. But it does not have implicit `this` pointer, because it is not called on an instance.

Comment: I see! Thank You!!